# Тире после части предложения с "это"

Tags: пунктуация

Какой знак следует поставит? 

Это называется (?) надежда.
Здесь всё ясно:
Это называется надеждОЙ

Comment: Не нужно тут никакого знака.

Comment: @Matt а если после этой конструкции будет полное простое предложение?

Comment: вы близки к тому, чтобы ваши вопросы закрывали как дубликаты - фактически вы спрашиваете об одном и том же.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тире - это пропущенный глагол есть/суть (глагол быть в настоящем времени).

> Мама - один из родителей.
> Мама есть один из родителей.
>
> Верёвка есть вервие простое.
> Верёвка - вервие простое.
>
> Мухоморы - грибы с красными шляпками с белыми точками.
> Мухоморы суть грибы с красными шляпками с белыми точками.

Конечно, это - не единственная возможная функция тире в русском языке, но в контексте вопроса - именно так.

Там где пропущенного глагола есть/суть нет - не нужно и тире

> Это называется "надежда". - нормально
> Это называется - "надежда". => Это называется есть "надежда". - ненормально

PS.

> Это называется надеждОЙ

Кстати, аналогично можно написaть в творительном падеже, что "мама является однИМ из родителей"

Comment: Благодарю за ответ. По делу и ясно!

Comment: Творительного падежа требуют глаголы:
Править, руководить, распоряжаться, командовать, управлять, верховодить, заведовать, увлекаться, интересоваться, заниматься, любоваться, восхищаться, восторгаться, наслаждаться, гордиться, восторгаться, восхищаться, пленяться, дорожить, владеть, пользоваться, обладать, овладевать, хвалиться, гордиться, хвастаться, клясться, торговать, жертвовать, рисковать, быть, стать, становиться, явиться, оказаться, остаться, считаться, слыть, называться и др. (кем? чем?)